# Crystal Report design and page settings got changed on IIS and other computers

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have developed a crystal reports based ASP.Net application. I have designed a crystal report. It works fine on development machine but when i deploy it on IIS or on another computer, page settings and design got changed. Now the report is not printing properly as what i designed and expected to see. Report is not displaying properly.

I also selected the **"No Printer"** option in print setup on Crystal Report but problem is still the same.

Please check attached screen print for![enter image description here][1] the issue.

Following is the issue on IIS and computers other then development computer.![enter image description here][2]

![enter image description here][2]

Comment: There are some crystal report ".JS" files please copy that file on IIS "aspnet_client" directory. These file you get  from your crystal report install locatios.

Comment: i copied those files, but those files are basically related to crystal reports menu bars, but that is displaying properly, the issues is-layout got messed up.

Comment: Please look at which release of runtime is installed on servers; some old ones  (Support Pack 3 - v. 13.0.3.x or Support Pack 4 - v. 13.0.4.x ) caused wrong rendering for some elements

Answer (score 1):

It's not version. In order to solve this problem, check **no printer** in **printer settings**

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed these steps yet?

1)  Copy the aspnet_client folder in the wwwroot directory.

2)  Go to the C\inetpub\wwwroot folder on any machine that has either/or crystal report runtime engine installations.

3)  Paste the aspnet_client folder into the website directory folder.  I assume this would work with a web application that was created from a virtual directory as well, just paste it into the virtual directory.

Comment: This is not an "aspnet_client" folder problem; missing "aspnet_client" causes "save-print" button not displaying, and "bobj undefined" error javascript error

Comment: Do you have the same runtime version on your deployment server and your dev machine?

Comment: I done on my server. But Now I changed my job place so no files I have