# Crsytal Report print setting changed on IIS

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have design crystal report in an ASP.Net web project. Crystal Report design is displaying fine when i run it on same computer where it got developed. But when i try to run it on different computer or deploy on IIS desgin is not displaying properly. 
When i designed crystal report it was One Note 2007 got selected in Printer Option.
I also tried using **No Printer** option but still the issue is not resolved.

Following are the attached images of working and non working crystal report.
[image: Report displayed on development computer]

[image: Report displayed on different computer or while deployed on IIS]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Crystal Report design and page settings got changed on IIS and other computers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19946589/crystal-report-design-and-page-settings-got-changed-on-iis-and-other-computers)

Comment: Ensure you have the same Crystal runtime (e.g. 13.0.7) on all machines.